# Lexical Analysis in C Language - How to make the asterisk be read and output it in detection of Multi-Line Comment?

Tags: c, lexical-analysis, lexical

I am working on a Lexical Analysis program , everything works fine when detecting a single line comment. This is my code for single line comment detection.

```
//Single Comment
if ((Current_Character == '/') && (fgetc(File_Input) == '/')){
    printf("%c", Current_Character);
    do{
        printf ("%c", Current_Character);
        Current_Character = fgetc (File_Input);
    }while(Current_Character != '\n');
    printf("\b \t | COMMENT\n", Current_Character);
    i = -1;
    Lexeme_Count++;
    Comment_Count++;
}
```

But when i am trying to detect the Multi-Line comment it got a logical error which it cannot detect the opening asterisk. here is my code for Multi-Line comment detection:

```
//Multi-Line Comment
if((Current_Character == '/') && (fgetc(File_Input) == '*')){ 
    printf ("%c", fgetc(File_Input));
    do{
        printf ("%c", Current_Character);
        Current_Character = fgetc(File_Input);
    }while(Current_Character != '/');

    printf("\b | COMMENT\n", Current_Character);
    i = -1;
    Lexeme_Count++;
    Comment_Count++;
}
```

Current character is for the first character for multi-line comment which is backslash and second character which is **(fgetc(File_Input)** (getting the next latest character from file) is for opening askterisk.

This is the content of the file I inputted:

```
#include <conio.h>

{

int a[3],t1,t2;

t1=2; a[0]=1; a[1]=2; a[t1]=3;

t2=

-

(a[2]+t1*6)/(a[2]

-

t1);

if t2>5 then

print(t2);

else {

int t3;

t3=99;

t2=

-

25;

print(

-

t1+t2*t3); // this is a comment on 2 lines

} endif /* THIS IS A MUTLI-LINE COMMENT  ON 2 LINES
*/ }
```

[This is my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW9h9.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
if((Current_Character == '/') && (fgetc(File_Input) == '*')){ 
    printf ("%c", fgetc(File_Input));
    do{
        printf ("%c", Current_Character);
        Current_Character = fgetc(File_Input);
    }while(Current_Character != '/');
```

The first `printf()` should be printing the character returned by the `fgetc()`, which you know to be a `*`, so you could use `putchar('*');` or (if you really insist) `printf("%c", '*')` or `printf("*")`.

Note that you've got another problem lurking:

```
x = a/b;
```

It isn't clear which of your comment blocks executes first, but both of them lose the `b` after the division.  There are numerous other subtleties in comment detection in C — I won't bore you with them all, but suffice to say "it is hard work removing comments in C" (and harder still in C++).  One of the issues you're not addressing is unexpected EOF (end of file).

You probably need a `peek()` function to look at the next character without consuming it:

```
int peek(FILE *fp)
{
    int c = fgetc(fp);
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetc(c, fp);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet skips all the chars until you detect the `*/`, considering the special cases where you have endings like `***/`:

```
int state = 0;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    switch(state) {
    case 0:
        switch(c) {
        case '*': state = 1; continue;
        default: /* process as comment char, but ignore */
            continue;
        } /* NOTREACHED */
    case 1:
        switch(c) {
        case '*': continue;
        case '/': /* end comment processing and return */
             state = 0;
             return COMMENT;  /* or continue, depending on scanner */
        default: /* any other char returns to state 0 */
             state = 0;
             /* process comment char */
             continue;
        } /* NOTREACHED */
    } /* switch */
} /* while */
```